# In Flutter, the card design does not behave like an ExpansionTile when clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's what I'm trying to do on the page I've designed; When I click on the Activities text, SuitableCards are displayed as a list in the form of ExpansionTile. But while doing this, I ran into some problems. The activities text is not written once, but writes as many elements as it pulls from the database. For example, if there are 3 files to be retrieved from the database, 'Activities' is written 3 times under each other. None of them are clicked and I don't see the list elements I'm trying to see. There is no important data in the SuitableCard widget. There is only design.

```
class Suitable extends StatefulWidget {
  const Suitable({super.key});

  @override
  State<Suitable> createState() => _SuitableState();
}

class _SuitableState extends State<Suitable> {
  late dynamic suitableActivities;
  late Map<dynamic, dynamic>? _user = null;

  // get user from SecureStorage
  void _getUser() {
    AuthManager.getUser().then((value) => {
          setState(() {
            _user = value;
          })
        });
  }

  Future<dynamic> fetchActivities() async {
    final response = await APIManager.call(
        "GET", "/daily-numerology/daily-activity-analyse");
    if (response["status"] == "success") {
      return response["data"];
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load activities');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _getUser();
    suitableActivities = fetchActivities();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
                future: suitableActivities,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final activities = snapshot.data as List<dynamic>;
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: activities.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return  return GestureDetector(
                        onTap:() {
                          SuitableCard(
                            image:
                            'https://images.pexels.com/photos/745045/pexels-photo-745045.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1',
                            title: activities[index]["title"],
                            cardTitle: 'Etkinlik',
                          );
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          child: Text('Activities'),
                        )
                      );
                        });
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                  }
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```